# Passing variables from external bash file not behaving as expected

Tags: bash, variables, backup, rsync

I have a bash script that’s using rsync to backup some files from my local desktop to a remote machine on my LAN.

I have the main script with some customisable variables in a separate .sh file to make for easy maintenance, deployment and git management.

So I have this dir structure

```
sync-backup-to-cp.sh
config/settings.sh
```

And the following code to include the config/settings.sh into the main sync-backup-to-cp.sh

```
#! /bin/bash

#load variables file
source /Users/enwhat/Dropbox/Flex/Scripts/mac/rysnc-backup-to-cp/config/settings.sh
```

However the imported variables aren’t behaving as expected. If I have any space in any of the variables it throws an error about the variables being invalid. It seems that bash is interpreting this oddly.

Ie. rsync_opts="--verbose --archive” will cause the script to break and run an error such as “invalid numeric arguments or unknown arguments supplied”. Where as rsync_opts="--verbose” runs perfectly.

To help illustrate the script I've taken some snippets of the code showing the flow with help so far

from: config / settings.sh

```
RSYNC_OPTS=( --bwlimit=1000 --verbose )
```

---

from my main script, there's a function call where these variables are passed in.

```
backup "$RSYNC_BIN" "$BACKUP_FILE_LIST" "$EXCLUDE_FILE_LIST" "$SSH_PORT" "$SSH_KEY" "$SOURCE" "$DESTINATION" "$RSYNC_OPTS[*]"
```

then the full function

```
function backup(){ #uses rsync to backup to server
    #takes 8 args 1

    #define local vars
    local l_rsync_bin=$1
    local l_rsync_backup_file_list=$2
    local l_rsync_exclude_file_list=$3
    local l_rsync_ssh_port=$4
    local l_rsync_ssh_key=$5
    local l_rsync_source=$6
    local l_rsync_dest=$7
    local l_rsync_opts=$8


    #local l_time
    #l_time=$(date)

    #caffinate stops system from sleeping
    echo ""$l_rsync_bin" "$l_rsync_opts" --verbose --archive --recursive --numeric-ids --human-readable --partial --progress --relative --itemize-changes --stats --rsync-path="sudo rsync" --delete-during --files-from="${l_rsync_backup_file_list}" --exclude-from="${l_rsync_exclude_file_list}" -e "ssh -q -p ${l_rsync_ssh_port} -i ${l_rsync_ssh_key}" "${l_rsync_source}" "${l_rsync_dest}""
    caffeinate -s "$l_rsync_bin" "$l_rsync_opts" --verbose --archive --recursive --numeric-ids --human-readable --partial --progress --relative --itemize-changes --stats --rsync-path="sudo rsync" --delete-during --files-from="${l_rsync_backup_file_list}" --exclude-from="${l_rsync_exclude_file_list}" -e "ssh -q -p ${l_rsync_ssh_port} -i ${l_rsync_ssh_key}" "${l_rsync_source}" "${l_rsync_dest}"

}
```

Comment: You're going to have to supply more details about how you use `rsync_opts`, but I can tell you now that `rsync "$rsync_opts"` will pass a single, unrecognized argument `--verbose --archive` to `rsync`, not two separate arguments `--verbose` and `--archive`.

Comment: @chepner rsync "$rsync_opts" is exactly how I'm doing it. With $rsync_opts set as a variable in the external bash variables file. Why is this not coming as two separate arguments and is there a fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are quoting `$rsync_opts`, the entire value is passed as a single, whitespace-containing argument to `rsync`. In order for each option to be passed as a separate argument, you need to leave the parameter expansion unquoted:

```
rsync $rsync_opts
```

However, you can't include arguments that actually contain whitespace like this; all whitespace is treated by the shell as separating arguments. The right way to store arguments is to use an array:

```
rsync_opts=( --verbose --archive )
rsync "${rsync_opts[@]}"
```

It may not be necessary for your current use case, but it's a good idea to get into the habit of doing things the right way to avoid nasty surprises later.

For example,

```
local -a l_rsync_opts
l_rsync_opts=(--bwlimit=1000 --verbose --rsync-path="sudo rsync")
```

---

UPDATE: Based on your edit, you need to do the following:

```
backup ... "${RSYNC_OPTS[@]}"   # @, not *

# Note the changes involving l_rsync_opts
function backup(){ #uses rsync to backup to server
    #takes 8 args 1

    #define local vars
    local l_rsync_bin=$1
    local l_rsync_backup_file_list=$2
    local l_rsync_exclude_file_list=$3
    local l_rsync_ssh_port=$4
    local l_rsync_ssh_key=$5
    local l_rsync_source=$6
    local l_rsync_dest=$7
    local l_rsync_opts=( "${@:8}" )


    #local l_time
    #l_time=$(date)

    #caffinate stops system from sleeping
    echo ""$l_rsync_bin" "${l_rsync_opts[@]}" --verbose --archive --recursive --numeric-ids --human-readable --partial --progress --relative --itemize-changes --stats --rsync-path="sudo rsync" --delete-during --files-from="${l_rsync_backup_file_list}" --exclude-from="${l_rsync_exclude_file_list}" -e "ssh -q -p ${l_rsync_ssh_port} -i ${l_rsync_ssh_key}" "${l_rsync_source}" "${l_rsync_dest}""
    caffeinate -s "$l_rsync_bin" "${l_rsync_opts[@]}" --verbose --archive --recursive --numeric-ids --human-readable --partial --progress --relative --itemize-changes --stats --rsync-path="sudo rsync" --delete-during --files-from="${l_rsync_backup_file_list}" --exclude-from="${l_rsync_exclude_file_list}" -e "ssh -q -p ${l_rsync_ssh_port} -i ${l_rsync_ssh_key}" "${l_rsync_source}" "${l_rsync_dest}"

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. It's helped me to make some progress. It now appears that the script is receiving the full list of arguments but they're getting wrapped in single quotes ''. Here's a little output from the script using set -x. I've been testing for the past hour but not been able to crack what's going wrong.

Comment: ```
+ local 'l_rsync_opts=--bwlimit=1000 --verbose --rsync-path="sudo rsync"'
+ caffeinate -s /usr/bin/rsync '--bwlimit=1000 --verbose --rsync-path="sudo rsync"' --archive --recursive --numeric-ids --human-readable --partial --progress --relative --itemize-changes --stats --delete-during --files-from=/Users/*****/backup_files --exclude-from=/Users/*****/exclude -e '"ssh' -q -p 22 -i '/Users/*******/"' / user@server:dest
rsync: --bwlimit=1000 --verbose --rsync-path="sudo rsync": invalid numeric value```

Comment: You have to use an array, not a regular parameter, since `l_rsync_opts` contains an argument which itself contains whitespace. The single quotes are fine; `set -x` always uses single quotes to quote characters, and it quotes the entire string.

Comment: I thought by passing in the variable from the settings.sh as ( --arg1 --arg2 ) and then passing that to my backup function as ${variable[*]} would then escape the full array correctly in a way that bash would be able to interpret it? I've added some snippets of the variables and functions in my code as I'm not grasping what's going wrong and I'd really appreciate the help @chepener

Comment: @chepener you're a genius. The last suggestion with ( "${@:8}" ) works. Thank you so much.

Comment: @chepener So I understand why this works, am I correct in saying... first we pass the whole array with each item escaped as "" individually. Then inside the backup function we captures that whole array at the positional parametre $@:8 into an array in the function? Ie. with local l_rsync_opts=( "${@:8}" )

Comment: That's right. It helps if you remember that you can't pass an array or part of an array as a single object; you're always expanding the (sub)array into separate elements to pass as individual arguments.